# Link to download iTMSTransporter for windows 7?

Tags: itmstransporter

iTunes Store Transporter (Transporter) is Apple's Java-based command-line tool for sending content to the iTunes Store. You can use Transporter to deliver your pre-generated audio and video content, in an iTunes Store Package (iTP package), to the iTunes Store.

Whether you are a large label or an encoding house, you can use Transporter to ensure your metadata and assets are properly delivered to the iTunes Store, validating the iTP packages against Apple's specifications.

Can someone provide me link to download iTMSTransporter for windows 7. 
I searched on net it only provides a .pkg file which is not opening in windows.

Answer (score 4):

I guess Apple hide it. Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/transporter/, input what version you want.

ex:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/transporter/1.8.3/iTMSTransporterToolInstaller_1.8.3.exe

Comment: Current version right now: iTMSTransporterToolInstaller_1.9.8.exe

Comment: I've found Transporter User Guide 2.0 https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide which has a section "Content-type details > Apps details". It has a link https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/Transporter__OSX/bin/ where I replaced Transporter__OSX by Transporter__windows and downloaded 2.0.0. You can replace it by Transporter__linux to download Linux version as well.

Answer (score 0):

iTMS is actually a part of Xcode and I'm afraid you cannot use it on a Windows machine natively at all.

Comment: Interesting.. I just noticed this in the help entry: `-WONoPause <arg>   The -WONoPause option is only valid on Windows...`

Comment: As far as I understand, it's a Java binary and can run on Windows. This guy seems to have it working: https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter#readme

Answer (score 0):

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/TransporterUserGuide/pdf

which can be found on iTunes Connect referenced by other PDF files there clearly indicates there *were* versions for other OS's.

However they have either been unintentionally omitted from the present site or Apple's docs are outdated.